# In Grails 3.2.6, Async controller actions lose access to SecurityContextHolder

Tags: grails, asynchronous, grails-3.0, grails3

This wasn't an issue in Grails 2 and only appears to now occur in Grails 3.  Any controller that invokes an async task is unable to access the SecurityContextHolder to get logged-in user information while rendering the view....

It appears that in SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, the SecurityContextHolder.clearContext() is being called before DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult is able to render, making rendering code unable to access logged-in user info stored in SecurityContextHolder :

```
    try {
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);

        chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());

    }
    finally {
        SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext();
        // Crucial removal of SecurityContextHolder contents - do this before anything
        // else.
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(),
                holder.getResponse());
        request.removeAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED);

        if (debug) {
            logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed");
        }
    }
```

At first I thought the issue was related to the security context not being passed into the Promise's runnable (or some such thing), and set springsecurity.sch.strategyName = "MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL" to no avail.

Here are some screenshots of showing the debugger:

1) This line in DispatcherServlet is not yet executed.  Watch statement at bottom of image shows .getAuthentication != null returns true

[image: Pre-handle execution]

2) Before SecurityContextHolder being cleared out in SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:
[image: Pre-security context clearing]

3) After returning from ha.handle, .getAuthentication() is now null
[image: SecurityContextHolder is now null]

4) getAuthentication() is now null before rendering view/result
[image]

To clarify, I am attempting to access springSecurityService.currentUser from within a custom tag library that is rendering the header of my page in a layout.

So, in a layout.gsp type file:

```
<header id="header" class="md-whiteframe-1dp">
<g:renderHeader/></header>
```

with a renderHeader definition like:

```
def renderHeader = { attrs, body ->

    SecUser currentUser = (SecUser) accountService.activeUser

    log.info("About to render header, session.id=" + session.id +
            (currentUser?.userLogLabel ?: " user=not_logged_in"))

    out << render(template: "/header", model: [currentUser : currentUser])
}
```

Comment: I'm beginning to feel that it has something to do when sitemesh is executing and async is involved that sitemesh has lost the handle on the SecurityContextHolder....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this same issue and managed to track it down.  I am assuming that you are using the [spring security core plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html).  The root issue is that the [plugin registers an application filter](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L207) without DispatcherType.ASYNC.  If you look at the Spring documentation, [spring security supports async](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-async).  To fix it I created this BeanPostProcessor and put it in my application context.

```
class SpringSecurityAsyncConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean in FilterRegistrationBean && "springSecurityFilterChainRegistrationBean".equals(beanName)) {
            //for some unknown reason the plugin only has this run for request and error, adding async as the spring documentation
            //says this is supported
            bean.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.<DispatcherType>of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC))
        }
        bean
    }

    @Override
    Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in controller or filter (and I mean 'filter' not 'interceptor')?

Because I can use it perfectly fine from a custom TokenFilter without issue.

This is why I argued heavily for moving communication away from business logic and higher up to filters and handler interceptors and to stop tying it to annotations and stuff. They keep running into these issues over and over.

I actually just released a faster version of Grails for API's that takes care of most of these communications issues yesterday for Universities

Comment: Where I'm noticing the issue is that my controller is rendering a view and the layout that the view uses has a custom tag that is accessing the SCH.  It's from inside that tag (that is helping to render content for the layout) that I'm seeing lost access to the logged in user.